# Failed to find Build Tools revision 31.0.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I had to reinstall Android Studio for some reason. After installing, I am not able to build my project, getting this error

Failed to find Build Tools revision 31.0.0

There's no warning or error showing in build.gradle file

[image]

I have tried changing compiledSdkVersion,buildToolsVersion and targetSdkVersion to 30

[image]

As you can see, if I change the version to 30, it is saying me to update to 31.

This is my project structure.

[image]

I have also tried Sync project with gradle files, Invalidate cashes, and restart, but no help. I don't know what to do now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem fixed.

Previously the class path in my project level gradle was 4.2.2, it was not showing any warning though.

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2"
```

I had to replace it with

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0'
```

And the project compiled successfully.

@SweetD3v's answer was helpful.

Comment: This was the solution for me. Once I bumped this version up I was able to correctly load the 31.0.0 build tools without error.

Answer (score 2):

in the app - `build.gradle` , change the buildToolsVersion to:

```
buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to replace the line containing `classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:<gradle_version>"` in your project level gradle with

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2"
```

It will add the latest gradle to your project.

If you still getting the error, then check if your compileSdkVersion & targetSdkVersion are 31.

Hope these little changes will solve your problem. :)

You will also need to change the "distributionUrl" in your `gradle-wrapper.properties` to `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-bin.zip`

And yes, as last option, try switching the buildToolsVersion from 31.0.0 to 30.0.2

Answer (score 1):

I changed my build tools version to 30.0.2 at the project structure tab and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

try this one, it worked for me

```
compileSdk 31

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.app"
    minSdk 23
    targetSdk 31
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

The Problem is you didn't installed the Android Studio build tools for the respective version.

**Step 1: Go to Android Studio:**

First Download the desired version in android studio > SDK manager > sdk Tools > android sdk build-tools 34 > 31.0.0    //install this in android studio.

**Step 2: Go to Terminal:**

```
 ~ cd home

 ~ cd yourDirectory   //eg:ashif

 ~ cd Android

 ~ cd build-tools

 ~ cd 31.0.0         //your desired build-tools version

 ~ cp d8 dx          //copy d8 and create directory dx

 ~ cd lib

 ~ cp d8.jar dx.jar  //copy d8.jar and create directory dx.jar

 ~ ls                //to list and check the changes
```

***That's it! It Works*** .